# Nicer way to deploy a minified Chrome extension

Tags: deployment, obfuscation, google-chrome-extension, minify

When deploying an extension I follow various steps : copy to a temporary folder all the files, copy/paste back and forth the code to the on-line minifiers / obfuscators and create the zip to be uploaded.

It's obvious that this could be simplified with scripting, but my experience on Windows scripting is very limited (most of my experience is server-side). Do I have to look back to the DOS .bat files like in the 90's or is there some cool tool or method I'm not aware?

Comment: What's wrong with batch files?  They serve plenty of solid purposes.  Don't bring a fire truck to a burning candle.

Comment: Nothing really wrong, but last time I edited one was about 15 years ago, the world has changed a lot since then, except the DOS prompt.

Comment: I've found gulp to be a very effective processor for this process. There are multiple steps, clean dirs, copy files, minify and renaming them, delete full versions, modify names or details within the manifest. Gulp does it all succinctly.

Comment: Yes that's is what I'm using, now, but I'm not sure if gulp existed 10 years ago :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides something like Ant, PHP is great for CLI scripting, even on Windows. Tons of built-in functions, including [.zip creation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php), and thorough docs.

IMO you'd be better off learning PHP (or Python, or anything else) than batch scripting.

Comment: Thanks, I know PHP, but I never thought to use it other than site building. Will look on this.

Comment: Just tested and found that PHP can work in windows without a Web server behind (may sound stupid, but I always used it for Web development). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) for builds. Maybe an overkill, but you can automate everything - minification (with 3rd party java libs), archiving, automatic license header insertion after minification.

I you are not familiar with Ant (or java) then it will be probably hard to jump right into it.

PS. Here is my open souce [extension](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-textarea-formatter/source/browse/) that uses Ant for builds, you can check it out (it copies files into a build folder, minifies, archives)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was looking for a tool running on Windows

Comment: @UVL It's java, it runs on any system (I have windows too). If you are looking for .exe app with GUI interface, well maybe someone else would be able suggest something, I don't know such thing...